# Error: Cannot find module '../deps/console.log'

Tags: node.js, npm, nodeunit

I'm on OS X 10.8.2, with Node.js 0.10.0 installed via homebrew. When I try to run `npm test` on [`nodegit`](https://github.com/tbranyen/nodegit), I get the following error:

```
cd test && nodeunit *.js

module.js:340
    throw err;
          ^
Error: Cannot find module '../deps/console.log'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:338:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:280:25)
    at Module.require (module.js:364:17)
    at require (module.js:380:17)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/faceleg/Work/Web/js-apprentice.com/Site/node_modules/nodegit/node_modules/.bin/nodeunit:11:1)
    at Module._compile (module.js:456:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:497:10)
npm ERR! Test failed.  See above for more details.
npm ERR! not ok code 0
```

I've done `npm update && npm -g update` since installing node 0.10.0.

How might I go about fixing this?

Comment: Is this a problem that effects your application? It may just be a problem with the specific module that is a known bug.

Comment: It's a problem because it prevents me from running unit tests

Comment: A workaround could be to create another test suite.

Comment: @ExxKA thanks, but I'm going to look into nodeunit's source to see if I can find the problem. There is no issue with my test suite, worked before upgrade.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The stack trace says it all, it's an issue with [nodeunit](https://github.com/caolan/nodeunit/blob/master/bin/nodeunit#L11). I'd file an issue on their [issues page](https://github.com/caolan/nodeunit/issues).

Not knowing much about nodeunit, it looks like it's anticipating being run from a different location. It's trying to require the file `/Users/faceleg/Work/Web/js-apprentice.com/Site/node_modules/nodegit/node_modules/deps/console.log.js` which is (probably) actually located at `/Users/faceleg/Work/Web/js-apprentice.com/Site/node_modules/nodegit/node_modules/nodeunit/deps/console.log.js`.

Comment: Yes I agree. Asking here to be sure my matching conclusion wasn't wrong. Thanks.

Comment: `nodeunit` looks dead. Likely going to switch to `node-tap`. Thanks